# How can I stop kile from automatic compiling

Tags: kile

Whenever I open or save a latex document, Kile automatically compiles it. It also does so when I open an input file which should not be compiled directly. This is almost like Word, which I hate because it believes to know better than myself what I want to do. I want to give the compilation command on my own initiative!  Is there any way to reach that much autonomy?

Comment: Are you talking about the Live Preview feature? If so, it should be possible to disable that in the config settings.

Comment: Thank you, Ingmar. No, I rarely use the Live Preview feature. I open my file with kile, and it automatically gets compiled. Same if I save the file. Particularly useless when the file is an input file into another one, and the latter is the one to be compiled. I searched the Kile menu to see where one might disable this function, no success - but nowadays menus are so vast that only specialists know where to find things.